# Automatic backup of changed text files using Mercurial (TortoiseHG)

Tags: svn, mercurial

I would like to set up an automatic backup of changed/saved text files using Mercurial. I already use the TortoiseHG as a collaboration tool with my colleague so I commit and synchronise the changes regularly. On top of it, I would like to have a "real time silent commit" as a backup tool just in case if anything goes wrong and I forget to commit manually. On the other hand I probably do not want to see those regular commits in the repository explorer as there would be thousands of them and it would be a mess.

Is there any best practise how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Mercurial is a good use case for this. Perhaps a backup tool like Second Copy or SuperFlexible or... would be a better fit.

You could probably write a plugin for HG that monitored file changes, but it certainly wasn't designed for that.

Comment: I see. So I will use Dropbox for that. Thanks for clarification that Mercurial is not a good tool for such a purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just a crontab with at 22:00 an rsync of your local working copies to an rsync server? If you have unpushed work, you know that it is also copied in an other place.

Comment: I would like to have it real-time as soon as any text file changes. This way I will always be able to go to any point in the history if I needed to and I will also be sure that I do not loose any data in case of program/computer crash...

Comment: Ok I see. rsync is really fast when nothing changes though. I had setup a save of my dokuwiki .txt files every 10 mn and it was taking almost no time when doing nothing.. that could be a middle ground.. Also most editors (e.g. emacs) save file editions every other keystroke, so you'd have three levels of recovery: editor, backup, repo. Good luck anyway.